# Performance issues with TeamCity after Ubuntu upgrade to 15.04

Tags: teamcity, ubuntu-15.04

After upgrading the Ubuntu to 15.04 we have encountered huge performance issues with TeamCity CI-server. It's taking 10-20% of CPU load and huge amounts of file reading. TeamCity takes over 5 minutes to start (most of time spent on Initializing TeamCity server components) and the whole server gets very slow on everything. I have enabled the default designated server JVM settings from the start scripts. Any ideas why this happens? Also tried with JDK 7 and 8.

TeamCity version: 9.1.3 (build 37176), but also had the same issues with 9.0.x version.

Comment: The cause can vary. Investigate the case using the [guideline](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Reporting+Issues#ReportingIssues-Slowness%2CHangingsandLowPerformance) from the documentation. If slow process is a TeamCity one, then please collect logs and other information according to the guideline and create issue in our [public tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/TW).

Comment: What jdk were you using before and after the upgrade?

Comment: We used openjdk-7-jdk before upgrade and tried with both openjdk-7-jdk and opendjk-8-jdk after upgrade without any improvement.